# URL-encoding VARCHAR and TEXT values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, encoding, plpgsql, url-encoding

Are there any well-known PL functions/libraries for extending a PostgreSQL (9.4.1) database with URL encoding (also known as *percent encoding*) capabilities?

Here's an example of the intended functionality:

- Input string: `International donor day: give blood for a good cause!`
- Output string: `International%20donor%20day%3A%20give%20blood%20for%20a%20good%20cause%21`

I guess an alternative would be to roll out my own implementation, since AFAIK there is currently no built-in way of doing this.

Comment: Are you aware that it is possible to use some languages like Python: plpython?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: indeed - I was just thinking that maybe there's a popular/universally accepted set of functions out there that I could use straight out of the box. I suppose that if I don't come across anything better, I will indeed have to write something myself (preferably using a high level PL like `plpython`).

Comment: URL encoding is a one liner in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial to do in an external PL,e.g.

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION urlescape(original text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE plpythonu AS $$
import urllib
return urllib.quote(original);
$$
IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. Note to anyone else reading this: In Python 3 the module hierarchy has been redesigned, so for `plpython3u` functions, use `urllib.parse.quote(original)` instead.